# System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found 'setids'

Tags: apex, soql, query, dynamic-soql

I keep getting the error:

> System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found 'setids'

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    Set<Id> setids = new Set<Id>();
    for(Task t : [SELECT WhatId FROM Task WHERE Is_Precall__c = true AND Is_Created_By_Batch__c = true AND CreatedDate = TODAY]){
        setids.add(t.WhatId);
    } 


    String q = 'SELECT Id, Route_Lookup__c, Next_Delivery_Date__c,';
         q += ' Market_Center_Lookup__c,';
         q += ' (SELECT Id FROM Orders__r WHERE Status = \'Pending\')';
         q += ' FROM ServicePoint__c WHERE Type__c = \'Active\'';
         q += ' AND Is_Batch_Exec_Date__c = true';
         q += ' AND Is_Precall_Customer__c = true';
         q += ' AND Id NOT IN setids' ;
    return Database.getQueryLocator(q);
}
```

Comment: replace **setids** by **:setids**

Comment: Drive-by downvoting is bad, people (shame on whoever did it). If I had to guess why this got downvoted, I'd say that it was because it is a pretty basic question which may have been able to be resolved by searching/googling for the error message. That said, this question contained the error message as well as the relevant code that was producing the error. I don't generally upvote questions that don't show research effort, but I will here to offset what I see as an undeserved downvote.

Comment: As an aside, Database.getQueryLocator can also accept an inline query, which avoids runtime errors by having the compiler warn you during deployment/development. You should use the string version **only** when you cannot predict the fields or conditions in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you reference an apex variable in a query (standard, or dynamic as is your case), you need to prefix the variable name with a colon `:`. This is called [expression binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm). You can still use expression binding in dynamic soql. Though there [are some additional considerations when using this with dynamic soql](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm), I don't believe any of them apply in this particular case.

The line in question here is

```
q += ' AND Id NOT IN setids' ;
```

and the correct way to do this would be

```
// Notice the colon (:) added before setids
q += ' AND Id NOT IN :setids';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your passing set variable **setids**  to an queryLocator on this line ,

```
q += ' AND Id NOT IN setids' ;
```

make correction on that line

```
q += ' AND Id NOT IN : setids' ; //add : before setids
```

Comment: I don't think that the particular question you linked to is too relevant to the question being asked here. There is a passing resemblance, but OP (**O**riginal **P**oster of the question) isn't trying to do anything near that level of complexity.